# What is the difference between Virtual Network (Classic) and Virtual Network in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Noticed Virtual Network and Virtual Network(Classic) in Azure, Wondering what is the difference between them and when to choose what ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure has two [different deployment models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json) for creating and working with resources: **Resource Manager** and **classic**.

How you create, configure, and manage your Azure resources is different between these two models. In classic mode, each resource provisioned in Azure is a single management unit. You manage all of the resources individually. The classic mode does not allow grouping of resources, which makes managing Azure resources difficult.

Azure resource management mode adds the concept of the resource group, which is a container for resources that share a common lifecycle. In ARM mode, you can deploy, manage, and monitor all the services for your solution as a group, rather than handling these services individually. Also, you can apply tags to resources to logically organize all the resources in your subscription.

When you interact with Classic mode resources from a command line such as Azure PowerShell, you are using **Azure Service Management API calls** (ASM). ASM is a traditional way of accessing Azure resources. In the Resource Manager mode, you are using [Azure Resource Manager Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/). When a user sends a request from any of the Azure tools, APIs, or SDKs, Resource Manager receives the request. It authenticates and authorizes the request. Resource Manager sends the request to the Azure service, which takes the requested action. See [Azure Resource Manager overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview).

The Virtual Network(Classic) is used for the classic models. Virtual Network in Azure is created for Resource Manager models. Currently, Microsoft recommends that you use Resource Manager for all new resources. Mostly, the Virtual Network(Classic) is used when you are creating a VNet for [cloud services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/) as far as I can tell. For Resource Manager resources, you just need to create Virtual Network in Azure portal.

> There are three scenarios to be aware of:
>
> - Cloud Services does not support Resource Manager deployment model.
> - Virtual machines, storage accounts, and virtual networks support both Resource Manager and classic deployment models.
> - All other Azure services support Resource Manager

Here is a blog about [Azure Classic vs Azure Resource Manager](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/04/05/azure-classic-vs-azure-resource-manager/)

> ***So which one should I use?***
>
> Since both modes are viable options at this point, it is necessary to
> pay careful attention to the features that each offer and your
> specific requirements. ARM cannot simply be assumed to be the best fit
> as it simply may not meet all of your or your customer’s needs.

Comment: Can you please add explanation for Classic Models and Resource Manager Models ?

Comment: Based on my understanding, simply saying, the Classic Models and Resource Manager Models are two different deployment modes on the Azure platform and each model will invoke differently API. Is the updated reply clear?